Is it possible to "side-by-side" load a DLL that is in a subdirectory?
I have a C++ application with embedded Python. I have put all Python files into a Libs directory, a subdirectory of my application.exe root.
In order to load Python, I need to move python310.dll to be side-by-side with my application.exe, not in Libs.
This split of python310.dll from the rest of Python is causing other issues, so I want it in Libs\python310.dll.
I have created an application.exe.manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Sampler"
        version="2.99.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="*"/>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                type="win32"
                name="python310"
                version="3.10.11150.1013"
                processorArchitecture="x86"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <file name=".\Libs\python310.dll"/>
</assembly>

However, this doesn't work. Running sxstrace, I get the error ERROR: Cannot resolve reference python310,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="3.10.11150.1013". The application won't start because it cannot find python310.dll.
Is it possible to use a manifest to load a DLL from a subdirectory?

This split of python310.dll from the rest of Python is causing other issues, so I want it in Libs\python310.dll. - can you elaborate on that?  Because the simplest solution is to have the EXE in the same directory  as the DLL. I'm putting some suggestions in an answer below, but I think the real problem is understand what the "other issues" are.

the standard way of resolving libraries is to add the path of the libraries to your environment PATH variable. The Windows system will then search each listed directory to find them.

@OldBoy - I was about to mention PATH hacks in my answer below. The challenge is that if the PATH is permanently changed by the app's installer, then other application could break. If OP finds a clever way to change PATH at runtime (e.g. script that launches EXE) without making it a system-wide or user-wide change, this could work well.

@selbie If a PATH change by an installer breaks other applications, then the creator is doing it wrong. The issue is that one needs to understand the way the OS (whether Windows, iOS or Linux) works, and follow the rules. Ii is a pity that too many modern coders don't seem to have that understanding.

This Microsoft documentation may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps

What do you mean by with embedded Python? Are you trying to create your own embedded Python installation. Why not use the official one?

I am using the official embedded python. To run it loads python310.dll, which currently needs to be side-by-side with the executable. The current executable is quite clean and accessed directly by the user. Putting all the Python files in there would add 30+ extra files and pollute that space. But splitting off Python310.dll is causing other issues, running specific Python commands. Ideally python310.dll is in it's default location and my executable can load it from a subdirectory, hence the question if this is possible via a manifest or not.

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79035863/2602410 Do that by a bootstrap exe.

Some suggestions.
Suggestion #1. It's easiest when all your DLLs and EXEs are in the same directory. Then you usually don't need a manifest file - at least not for native code.  Ask yourself this - does the end user care if all the python, DLL, and EXE files were in the same directory if the code just worked?  So consider just merging your "lib" and and "application" directory to be one and the same.
Suggestion #2.  Split your EXE up into two binaries: a stub exe and a DLL where most of your code is linked to.  Application.exe is just a stub executable who's only job is to invoke SetDllDirectory("c:\path\to\app\ \lib" at runtime with the  followed by LoadLibrary("application.dll") that links to all your Python stuff in the lib directory.  Then GetProcAddress for a special main function that you export from this DLL.
Now your native application code will default to searching the lib path for DLLs as needed since you've invoked SetDllDirectory programmatically.


does the end user care if all the python, DLL, and EXE files were in the same directory if the code just worked
Yes they do care, as this installation directory is where they access the application and adding 30+ files from the Python install will be confounding. This can't be changed in the short-term due to operations.
Suggestion #2 might the long-term solution

